# What is the difference between .one() and .scalar()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

What is the main difference between `.one()` and `.scalar()` in SQLAlchemy, as both doing the same jobs.

I saw some sites like [tutorialpoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_returning_list_and_scalars.htm) but that explanation is not enough for me to understand clearly

Answer (score 62, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has nice documentation.

`one()`

> Return exactly one result or raise an exception.
>
> Raises sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound if the query selects no rows.
> Raises sqlalchemy.orm.exc.MultipleResultsFound if multiple object
> identities are returned, or if multiple rows are returned for a query
> that returns only scalar values as opposed to full identity-mapped
> entities.

Link on [one()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) method

`scalar()`

> Return the first element of the first result or None if no rows
> present. If multiple rows are returned, raises MultipleResultsFound.

Link on [scalar()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar) method.

and if you will have some questions related to **SQLAlchemy** my recommendation - first of all, to check the documentation, since it's really powerful and clean.

**UPD:**

Since the answer contains old links and for the 1.4 version of SQLAlchemy.

Here are links for version 2.0

- [Query.scalar()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar)
- [Query.one()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.one)

Comment: Hi mikeylight, "Return the first element of the first result or None if no rows present. If multiple rows are returned, raises MultipleResultsFound." this same thing is done by .one() also, I think. what is the advantage of .scalar() over .one() or viceversa?

Comment: You'd use `one()` to fetch one and only one model object or result tuple, `scalar()` to fetch a scalar value such as the result of an aggregate like `max()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, both one and scalar works with aggregate functions perfectly. where as output of aggregate function shows for 
1.`.one()` => (5,).












































2.`.scalar()` => 5.

Comment: Which is what I said: "You'd use `one()` to fetch one and only one ... result tuple". Also note the "such as", which implies that it's not only for aggregates.

Comment: agree with @IljaEverilä

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen and I hope that things came a little bit clear for you

Comment: The version 2.0 links point to old legacy methods.  For v2.0, I used scalar_one() instead of scalar(). Here's the link I used for it: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar_one

Comment: Thank you! I updated the links with the correct links.

Answer (score 40):

Here is the difference and when to use each:

**When to use `one()`:**
If you have a query that should return 1 result, otherwise raise an exception – even if it returns 0 results. *In other words, it **does not allow** `empty results`.*

**When to use scalar():**
If you have a query that either returns 1 result or no results. Otherwise throw an exception. *In other words, it **does allow** `empty results`.*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it directly addresses the OP's question (and answered it for me too!). Thanks.

Comment: this is clear and succinct and exactly what i needed to know, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

In SQLAlchemy 2.0 style, the result format is also different.

`one()` returns [`Row` object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) (named-tuple):

```
>>> session.execute(select(Note)).one()
(<Note>,)
```

while `scalar()` returns a single element (the first element of the Row object/tuple):

```
<Note>
```

If you want to get the single element with `one()`, you can call it with `scalars()`:

```
>>> session.execute(select(Note)).scalars().one()
```

Or use the `scalar_one()` shortcut:

```
>>> session.execute(select(Note)).scalar_one()
```

See the 2.0 migration docs for more details: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-orm-usage