# SqlAlchemy asyncio orm: How to query the database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

In SqlAlchemy async orm engine how do I query a table and get a value or all?

I know from the non async methods that I can just do

`SESSION.query(TableClass).get(x)`

but trying this with the async methods it throws the next error:

`AttributeError: 'AsyncSession' object has no attribute 'query'.`

Here's my SESSION variable defined. The LOOP variable is just `asyncio.get_event_loop()` used to start async methods when my sql module is loaded and populate variables used as a cache to avoid caching the database every time I need somethin:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

from .. import CONFIG, LOOP

def _build_async_db_uri(uri):
    if "+asyncpg" not in uri:
        return '+asyncpg:'.join(uri.split(":", 1))
    return uri

async def start() -> declarative_base:
    engine = create_async_engine(_build_async_db_uri(CONFIG.general.sqlalchemy_db_uri))
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        BASE.metadata.bind = engine
        await conn.run_sync(BASE.metadata.create_all)
    return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, class_=AsyncSession))


BASE = declarative_base()
SESSION = LOOP.run_until_complete(start())
```

Here's an example of table and cache function:

```
class TableClass:
    __tablename__ = "tableclass"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    alias = Column(Integer)

CACHE = {}
async def _load_all():
    global CACHE
    try:
        curr = await SESSION.query(TableClass).all()
        CACHE = {i.id: i.alias for i in curr}

LOOP.run_until_complete(_load_all())
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> session.query is the old API. The asynchronous version uses *select* and accompanying methods.

```
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = create_async_engine(_build_async_db_uri(CONFIG.general.sqlalchemy_db_uri))
async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession
)


CACHE = {}
async def _load_all():
    global CACHE
    try:
        async with async_session() as session:
            q = select(TableClass)
            result = await session.execute(q)
            curr = result.scalars()
            CACHE = {i.id: i.alias for i in curr}
    except:
        pass

LOOP.run_until_complete(_load_all())
```

You can read more about SqlAlchemy Asynchronous I/O [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html)

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link. I've noticed something there. In an further example there's a small implementation using the legacy API (the non asyncio one) in an awaitable. Would the non async function will be executed asyncio if I use run_async?

Comment: Yes sure. You always can use the old API with synchronous engine and session

Comment: What is this called exactly? It will be easier to search if I know the exact name of this `q = select(TableClass)` this type of query.

Comment: @HarshitSinghai This is sqlalchemy core. Here is documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/

Answer (score 11):

##### Querying by the primary key

> New in version 1.4: Added Session.get(), which is moved from the now deprecated Query.get() method.

```py
  id = 1
  user = await session.get(User, id)
```

[Session.get - SQLAlchemy 1.4 documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get)

##### Querying by other columns

The way to go is using select statements.

```py
statement = select(User).where(User.name == 'John')
result = await session.execute(statement)

# This will return a collection of users named 'John'
johns : list[User] = result.scalars.all()

# This will take the first 'John'
first_john : User = result.scalar()

# This will take one result. 
# If your query has more than one result, an exception will be thrown. 
# Use it only if you're expecting a single result
john : User = result.scalars.one()
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591326/8843585

[select - SQLAlchemy 1.4 documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select)

[execute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.execute)

[More examples](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/quickstart.html)

Comment: `scalars` should be called. Correct calls are `result.scalars().all()` and `result.scalars().one()`

Comment: Actually we're both wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55663214/8843585 
`scalar()` does work, similarly to `scalars().one()`, which throws error if multiple results are found.