# What is the `ScalarResult` wrapper for and should I use it at service level?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've read a [thread on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662957/what-is-the-difference-between-one-and-scalar) but haven't found an answer to my question.

In other words, do the methods do the same thing. Or do they have differences? And which one would be better at the service and at repository level?

```py
from .models import MyModel


class Repository:
    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession):
        self._session = session

    async def get_by_id(self, _id: int) -> ScalarResult[MyModel]:
        return self._session.scalar(
            select(MyModel).where(MyModel.id == _id)
        )

    async def get_by_id_without_wrapper(self, _id: int) -> MyModel:
        scalar = self._session.scalar(
            select(MyModel).where(MyModel.id == _id)
        )
        return scalar.one_or_none()  # This is the difference between the previous thread
```

What's the wrapper `ScalarResult` do (apart from raw data extraction)?

Comment: Your `get_by_id()` method does not return a `ScalarResult` object; It returns a `MyModel` object, or `None` if there is no MyModel object with the specified `id`. Did you intend for that method to call `self._session.scalars()` instead of `self._session.scalar()` ?